# spark-sql overwrite hive table ,why occured duplicate records

Tags: apache-spark-sql

It occured duplicate records  when spark-sql overwrite hive table . when spark job has failure stages,but dateframe has no  duplicate records? when I run the job again, the reasult is correct.It confused me.why?

eg:
dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("outputTable");

no duplicate records in dataFrame,
but duplicate records existed in hive outputTable

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: More information is need. ie spark version. By the way, I found the bug issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24589